# How can I ask a question about drupal.org?

Tags: discussion

I just created this question: [Get more drupal.org project usage information](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87971/get-more-drupal-org-project-usage-information) but it is really about drupal.org and not drupal -is there a way to tag it appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already got [community-drupal-org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-drupal-org), that'll probably cover it :)

I suspect you probably meant [Best way to get module and commit meta data from drupal.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160386/best-way-to-get-module-and-commit-meta-data-from-drupal-org/160392#160392) (which didn't have that tag but does now)

Comment: That was what I needed, but suggest changing the tag to drupal-org-community as I think that is more intuitive for typing in the widget.  I do not yet have tag management powers :)

Comment: BTW - I just got down voted because the question is about drupal.org - which I think is not appropriate (especially given the community-drupal.org tag!) see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160543/where-do-i-make-a-feature-request-to-drupal-org/160551#160551